# Merge Tables: classify output according to how rows where joined

Tags: r, merge

While joining (large, complex) tables in R, I usually struggle to sanity check the results from this operation. 
See here a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(data.table) 
table1 <- data.table(id=c("A", "B", "C"), price=c(12,11,10))
table2 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C", "D"), wharehouse=c("Colorado","Texas","New York", "Oregon"))


table_join <- merge(table1,table2,
                    by="id",
                    all.x=T,
                    all.y=T)
```

The expected output it is not rocket science:

```
structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), price = c(12, 
                                                          11, 10, 10, NA), wharehouse = c("Colorado", NA, "Texas", "New York", 
                                                                                          "Oregon"), join = c("INNER JOIN", "LEFT JOIN", "INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN", 
                                                                                                              "INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN", "RIGHT JOIN")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                               -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

But I would like to know how many rows did not match the other table, have one match, multiple matches...

I would like some info (maybe a new row) describing how resulted from the merge. See a possible example:

```
table_join[1, join:="INNER JOIN"]
table_join[2, join:="LEFT JOIN"]
table_join[3, join:="INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN"]
table_join[4, join:="INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN"]
table_join[5, join:="RIGHT JOIN"]
```

Here the "expected output"

```
structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), price = c(12, 
11, 10, 10, NA), wharehouse = c("Colorado", NA, "Texas", "New York", 
"Oregon"), join = c("INNER JOIN", "LEFT JOIN", "INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN", 
"INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN", "RIGHT JOIN")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

For sure, with big tables could appear new situations (full cartesian joins), matches were the `id` exists on the other table but with `NAs` (in my example let say we have id `D` but price `NA`).

Also, it will help me to trace complex situations when merging multiple tables

Does a wrapper of merge exist in R that performs such operation? I remember when a was a young, dreamy Research Assistant that Stata was able to do something related, but I do not know how to do it automatically in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem per se is quite easy and it is solved by tracking the id's frequency of each table. Below follows my solution, but it will probably need some optimization for large tables.

**EDIT1:**

Bug fixing: category was overwritten; `eval(track.col)` instead of `eval(parse(text = track.col)))`

Moreover it is now possible to assign a *custom name* to the `join` column.

```
library(data.table)

track.merge <- function(x, y, on, track.col){

  x[, N := .N, by = on][]
  y[, N := .N, by = on][]

  table_join <- merge(x, y, by=on, all.x=T, all.y=T)

  x[, N := NULL, by = on][]
  y[, N := NULL, by = on][]

  table_join[N.x > 1 & N.y > 1,                              
             eval(track.col) := "INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT RIGHT JOIN"][]

  table_join[N.x > 1 & is.na(eval(parse(text = track.col))), 
             eval(track.col) := "INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT JOIN"][]

  table_join[N.y > 1 & is.na(eval(parse(text = track.col))), 
             eval(track.col) := "INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN"][]

  table_join[is.na(N.x),                                     
             eval(track.col) := "RIGHT JOIN"][]

  table_join[is.na(N.y),                                
             eval(track.col) := "LEFT JOIN"][]

  table_join[is.na(eval(parse(text = track.col))),      
             eval(track.col) := "INNER JOIN"][]

  table_join[, ':=' (N.x = NULL, N.y = NULL)][]
}
```

**EDIT2**

A much more readable version of the same function

```
track.merge2 <- function(x, y, on, track.col){

  x[, N := .N, by = on][]
  y[, N := .N, by = on][]

  table_join <- merge(x, y, by=on, all.x=T, all.y=T)
  track_ids <- character(NROW(table_join))

  x[, N := NULL, by = on][]
  y[, N := NULL, by = on][]

  track_ids[table_join$N.x > 1 & table_join$N.y > 1] <- "INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT RIGHT JOIN"
  track_ids[table_join$N.x > 1 & track_ids == ""]    <- "INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT JOIN"
  track_ids[table_join$N.y > 1 & track_ids == ""]    <- "INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN"
  track_ids[is.na(table_join$N.x)]                   <- "RIGHT JOIN"
  track_ids[is.na(table_join$N.y)]                   <- "LEFT JOIN"
  track_ids[track_ids == ""]                         <- "INNER JOIN"

  table_join[[track.col]] <- track_ids
  table_join[, ':=' (N.x = NULL, N.y = NULL)][]
}
```

**TEST:**

```
table1 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C", "B", "F", "H", "H"), price=c(12,11,10,13,10,15,3)) 
table2 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C", "F", "F", "H", "L"), wharehouse=c("Colorado","Texas","New York", "Washington", "Illinois", "Florida", "Kansas")) 

> table1
   id price
1:  A    12
2:  C    11
3:  C    10
4:  B    13
5:  F    10
6:  H    15
7:  H     3

> table2
   id wharehouse
1:  A   Colorado
2:  C      Texas
3:  C   New York
4:  F Washington
5:  F   Illinois
6:  H    Florida
7:  L     Kansas

> track.merge(table1, table2, "id", "join")
    id price wharehouse                                 join
 1:  A    12   Colorado                           INNER JOIN
 2:  B    13       <NA>                            LEFT JOIN
 3:  C    11      Texas INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT RIGHT JOIN
 4:  C    11   New York INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT RIGHT JOIN
 5:  C    10      Texas INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT RIGHT JOIN
 6:  C    10   New York INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT RIGHT JOIN
 7:  F    10 Washington      INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN
 8:  F    10   Illinois      INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN
 9:  H    15    Florida       INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT JOIN
10:  H     3    Florida       INNER JOIN. MULTIPLE LEFT JOIN
11:  L    NA     Kansas                           RIGHT JOIN


> all.equal(track.merge2(x, y, on = "id", "join"), track.merge(x, y, on = "id", "join"))
[1] TRUE
```

Considering tables with 1000k rows and two columns merging is ~2.5x slower:

```
library(microbenchmark)

table1 <- data.table(id = sample(1e+6, 1e+6, replace = T), price = rnorm(1e+6))
table2 <- data.table(id = sample(1e+6, 1e+6, replace = T), state = sample(LETTERS, 1e+6, replace = T))

microbenchmark(merge        = merge(table1,table2, by="id", all.x=T, all.y=T),
               track.merge  = track.merge(table1, table2, "id", "join"), 
               track.merge2 = track.merge2(table1, table2, "id", "join"), 
               times = 10L)

         expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
        merge  569.7727  573.433  577.8784  577.2759  581.9219  586.9951    10 a  
  track.merge 1456.4417 1536.982 1545.6427 1556.5226 1563.6150 1623.3078    10   c
 track.merge2 1392.6832 1464.968 1460.2484 1471.0332 1477.2330 1487.1828    10  b
```

**COMMENT ON MISSING IDS**

From a database perspective it does not make much sense having NAs as id. Ids are the key to relate your tables into a relational database. If there are records with missing ids it is pointless to relate them with other table, so I'd either filter them out or try to fix them **before** merging tables.

Comment: Well, the devil is in the details. Check: 
`table1 <- data.table(id=c("C", "C", "C"), price=c(12,11,10))
table2 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C", "D"), wharehouse=c("Colorado","Texas","New York", "Oregon"))
`
track.merge(table1,table2,"id")` or `table1 <- data.table(id=c(NA, "C", "C"), price=c(12,11,10))
table2 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C", NA), wharehouse=c("Colorado","Texas","New York", "Oregon"))

track.merge(table1,table2,"id")`  And what happens when there is a column named join? But I think it is a good first draft

Comment: Check `table1 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C"), price=c(12,11,10))
table2 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C"), wharehouse=c("Colorado","Texas","New York"))`

Comment: @JonnyCrunch I've edited again. The custom column name feature makes the function much less readable, if not essential I'd consider removing it. Another way would be to return a character vector (unnamed). I see what I can do

Comment: It has been a long way, but thank you very much! The bounty is yours! BTW: I dont care about being slower, I will save a lot more time by knowing how my tables matched!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using `dplyr`. Just as @Gerald T said, you can get all the information by looking at the merged table.

You can get the frequency table using this code.

```
library(tidyverse)
table1 %>% left_join(table2) %>% 
      group_by(id) %>%
      summarise(num_wharehouse = sum(!is.na(wharehouse)))
```

> ```
> Joining, by = "id"
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>   id    num_wharehouse
>   <chr>          <int>
> 1 A                  1
> 2 B                  0
> 3 C                  2
> ```

Then you can get the statistics you want.

```
table1 %>% left_join(table2) %>% 
          group_by(id) %>%
          summarise(num_wharehouse = sum(!is.na(wharehouse))) %>%
          summarise(merged = sum(num_wharehouse > 0),
                    not_merged = sum(num_wharehouse == 0), 
                    single_match = sum(num_wharehouse == 1),
                    multi_match = sum(num_wharehouse > 1))
```

> ```
> Joining, by = "id"
> # A tibble: 1 x 4
>   merged not_merged single_match multi_match
>    <int>      <int>        <int>       <int>
> 1      2          1            1           1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

My package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin) intends to tackle the wider problem of checks on joins. It doesn't give you exactly what you ask but hopefully close enough, possibly better as it does the checks that you might be doing as a next step.

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
safe_full_join(table1, table2, check="uvmn")
  id price wharehouse
1  A    12   Colorado
2  B    11       <NA>
3  C    10      Texas
4  C    10   New York
5  D    NA     Oregon
Warning messages:
1: x has unmatched sets of joining values: 
    id
1:  B 
2: y has unmatched sets of joining values: 
    id
1:  D 
3: y is not unique on id
```

Checks are handled by a single string parameter, i.e. a sequence of characters, where uppercase letters trigger failures, lower case letters trigger warnings, and letters prefixed with `~` trigger messages, the codes used here ([there are more](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin)) are as follow:

- `"u"` like unique to check that the join columns form an unique key on x
- `"v"` to check that the join columns form an unique key on y
- `"m"` like match to check that all rows of x have a match
- `"n"` to check that all rows of y have a match

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper function can be applied following the join to analyze its path as follows.  Scenarios given in OP and comments:

```
#Scenario 1
table1 <- data.table(id=c("A", "B", "C"), price=c(12,11,10)); table2 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C", "D"), wharehouse=c("Colorado","Texas","New York", "Oregon"));

#Scenario 2
table1 <- data.table(id=c("C", "C", "C"), price=c(12,11,10)); table2 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C", "D"), wharehouse=c("Colorado","Texas","New York", "Oregon"));

#Scenario 3
table1 <- data.table(id=c(NA, "C", "C"), price=c(12,11,10)); table2 <- data.table(id=c("A", "C", "C", NA), wharehouse=c("Colorado","Texas","New York", "Oregon")) 

#Scenario 4
table1 <- data.table(id=c("A", "A", "C"), price=c(12,11,10)); table2 <- data.table(id=c("B", "C", "C","D"), wharehouse=c("Colorado","Texas","New York", "Oregon")) 

setkeyv(table1,"id")
setkeyv(table2,"id")
table_join  <- merge(table1,table2,by="id",all.x=T,all.y=T)

write_description <- function(p,w,n) { 
  inners <- (!is.na(p) & !is.na(w))
  lefts <-  (!is.na(p) & is.na(w))
  rights <- ((is.na(p) & !is.na(w))) | (n > 1 & !is.na(w))
  multis <- n > 1

  paste0(ifelse(inners,"INNER JOIN ",""),
         ifelse(multis,"MULTIPLE ",""),
         ifelse(lefts,"LEFT JOIN ",""),
         ifelse(rights,"RIGHT JOIN ",""))
}


table_join[,description:=write_description(price,wharehouse,.N),by="id"]
```

Results SCENARIO 1:

```
> table_join
   id price wharehouse                     description
1:  A    12   Colorado                     INNER JOIN 
2:  B    11         NA                      LEFT JOIN 
3:  C    10      Texas INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
4:  C    10   New York INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
5:  D    NA     Oregon                     RIGHT JOIN
```

Results: SCENARIO 2

```
> table_join
   id price wharehouse                     description
1:  A    NA   Colorado                     RIGHT JOIN 
2:  C    12      Texas INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
3:  C    12   New York INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
4:  C    11      Texas INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
5:  C    11   New York INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
6:  C    10      Texas INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
7:  C    10   New York INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
8:  D    NA     Oregon                     RIGHT JOIN
```

Results: SCENARIO 3

```
> table_join
   id price wharehouse                     description
1: NA    12     Oregon                     INNER JOIN 
2:  A    NA   Colorado                     RIGHT JOIN 
3:  C    11      Texas INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
4:  C    11   New York INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
5:  C    10      Texas INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
6:  C    10   New York INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN
```

Results: SCENARIO 4

```
> table_join
   id price wharehouse                     description
1:  A    12         NA             MULTIPLE LEFT JOIN 
2:  A    11         NA             MULTIPLE LEFT JOIN 
3:  B    NA   Colorado                     RIGHT JOIN 
4:  C    10      Texas INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
5:  C    10   New York INNER JOIN MULTIPLE RIGHT JOIN 
6:  D    NA     Oregon                     RIGHT JOIN
```

Comment: See my comment to Gerald, please.

Comment: In your 3rd scenario where id=NA does it imply you want to merge by id values that are NA or to omit these?  The merge() function will treat these as key values and merge will be fine unless it's not desired behavior?

Comment: Looking over your additional scenarios, the approach holds _as consistent_ with the example given in the structure() -- the question arises if a valid INNER join would seek to also indicate a LEFT join?  In the example, merge on "A" yields only INNER, but this is also a valid LEFT join (for both "A" and "C"), but this is not articulated in structure() example?